# Как получить элемент без ошибки?

Tags: javascript

Iframe создаётся через 5 секунд после загрузки сайта и textarea, полученная таким способом -  `document.querySelector('iframe textarea')`, в тот момент равняется null. А когда `iframe` создан скрипт работает, но всё что после него нет. Как сделать чтобы весь остальной скрипт после получения `textarea` работал и также после создания iframe скрипт с получением textarea тоже работал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.querySelector('selector') !== null) {
  // code...
}
```